# error code 401 when call ping search image api

Tags: authentication, search, images

https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/images/search?Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key=9e572eb4609e4042b490fc42b2cb004c&q=apples

{"error":{"code":"401","message":"Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription and use a correct regional API endpoint for your resource."}}

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

That key works fine if you [follow the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/bing-web-search/search-the-web).

```
curl -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: 9e572eb4609e4042b490fc42b2cb004c" https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/search?q=apples

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

The documentation says that the key should be passed as a header, not as a query parameter. If you're just clicking on that link in a browser it's not going to work that way. You need to write code that adds the header. A lot of developers use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) for testing purposes.

**Side note:** The key should also probably be considered a secret because anyone who knows it can use up all your quota and if you're a paying customer you'll end up having to pay for what they use. Now that this one has been published you should delete it, create a new one and keep that one secret.